# Need Jython output in the form of Excel

Tags: excel, jython, websphere-8

```
applist = AdminApp.list().split("\n")
for a in applist:
    print a
    continue
```

I need the output of this script in the form of excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to create and write data to an Excel file with Jython. There are several ways to do it:

1. You can use Java from Jython and use Apache POI - [example](https://wiki.python.org/jython/PoiExample)
2. You can simply write to a CSV file, and on Windows, Excel should open it automatically.
3. You can use a Python library like xlwt or openpyxl.
   You'll have to install it, e.g.: `easy_install openpyxl`.
   Then you can follow the tutorial [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) You didn't say if this code runs on your WebSphere instance, if so it may be a bit harder to install a Python module, but surely not impossible.